# Functional Purpose of Flattened 7th Chord

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions

I am wondering how to use the "flattened seventh" chord when used in a major key (i.e. B-flat Major chord in key C Major).  I believe this would put a piece in the mixolydian mode.  For example . . . I know that a diminished 7th essentially serves the same purpose as a V7 chord, but where do you go from the flattened 7th . . . how do you go to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In classical functional harmony, non-diatonic chords are usually diatonic to a related tonal center, so the answer is that it depends on what the local tonal center is.  Normally, the ♭Ⅶ chord will be taken from the parallel minor or a related key.  For example, it can be Ⅴ/♭Ⅲ, where ♭Ⅲ is the relative major of the parallel minor.

The first example that comes to mind, however, is the ♭Ⅶ in *Begin the Beguine,* which itself is the tonal center of the first phrase of the bridge: ⅱ/♭Ⅶ → Ⅴ7/♭Ⅶ → ♭Ⅶ.  Overall, the bridge shifts the tonal center, roughly in the parallel minor, from ⅰ (the same as ⅱ/♭Ⅶ) to ♭Ⅶ to ♭Ⅵ to Ⅴ.  These shifts are achieved by lowering the major third that ended the preceding phrase to the minor third:

- ⅰ (= ⅱ/♭Ⅶ) → Ⅴ<sup>7</sup>/♭Ⅶ → ♭Ⅶ
- ♭ⅶ (= ⅱ/♭Ⅵ) → Ⅴ<sup>7</sup>/♭Ⅵ → ♭Ⅵ<sup>7</sup>

The next chord is a diminished seventh achieved by raising the root of the preceding chord by a half step.  This leads to ⅶ°<sup>7</sup>/Ⅴ and then to a period of alternation between various minor subdominant functions and the dominant, where the bridge ends.  The last phrase definitively reestablishes the major key by starting with the tonic Ⅰ chord.

Comment: This answer is correct. I'll just add that this technique is usually referred to as "mode mixture," the chords taken from the related key are called "borrowed chords."